# Azure functions on Premises - Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container

Tags: azure, docker, hyper-v, azure-functions-runtime

I am working with Azure Functions on Premises V2 (Runtime).

Trying to test a simple function that is executed each minute and write in logs.

However Function is not executed, and I am getting this error.

It is running on a Virtual Machine with Windows server 2016.
(what I think could be causing this problem).

I am new wiht Docker and Hyper-V, any help will be appreciated.

There are some command lets I can execute, to comprobate if Hyper V and
Docker are running well ?

Thank You in Advance.

This is the Log I'm getting.

3/14/2018 5:42:44 PM Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.3/14/2018 5:41:48 PM [myteslaVM] Function App 'MyContainerFuncApp' is starting...3/14/2018 5:41:49 PM [myteslaVM] Pull container image azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver3/14/2018 5:41:50 PM [myteslaVM] preview2-latest-nanoserver: Pulling from azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime3/14/2018 5:41:50 PM [myteslaVM] Digest: sha256:dfdb47a7638d0cdd1a42c603e3e59311ee0d229222f88329a7c561fc3d8b2ff33/14/2018 5:41:50 PM [myteslaVM] Status: Image is up to date for azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver

3/14/2018 5:41:50 PM [myteslaVM] The container image azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver has been pulled successfully!
3/14/2018 5:41:50 PM [myteslaVM] Provisioning container MyContainerFuncApp_03/14/2018 5:41:51 PM [myteslaVM] f2788b6c9c5d6115bba891f463759dd0df75c2344e6c217b0280a8b9f686fb32
3/14/2018 5:41:51 PM [myteslaVM] C:\Program Files\Azure Functions Runtime\docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container f2788b6c9c5d6115bba891f463759dd0df75c2344e6c217b0280a8b9f686fb32

```
encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"f2788b6c9c5d6115bba891f463759dd0df75c2344e6c217b0280a8b9f686fb32","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\Program Files\\Azure Functions Runtime\\docker\\windows\\windowsfilter\\f2788b6c9c5d6115bba891f463759dd0df75c2344e6c217b0280a8b9f686fb32","Layers":[{"ID":"951f96e7-ad8c-5e5c-8533-4f70d49a4e6a","Path":"C:\\Program Files\\Azure Functions
```

"HostName":"f2788b6c9c5d","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\windows\temp\fwas\mycontainerfuncapp","ContainerPath":"c:\home","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["d6c4c527-5520-40f1-9c84-2f3d8a013900"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\Program Files\Azure Functions Runtime\docker\windows\windowsfilter\545c1be2ad30f1933a07de48e4ffe611900bacafbf4b717de969b56fb8a725d6\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.

3/14/2018 5:41:51 PM [myteslaVM] Issuing stop command to container: MyContainerFuncApp_

```
    03/14/2018 5:41:52 PM [myteslaVM] Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: MyContainerFuncApp_0: No such container: MyContainerFuncApp_03/14/2018 5:41:52 PM [myteslaVM] Stop complete for container: MyContainerFuncApp_03/14/2018 5:41:52 PM [myteslaVM] ExecuteCommand called with C:\Program Files\Azure Functions Runtime\docker\docker.exe returned 125.3/14/2018 5:42:03 PM [myteslaVM]

    Function App 'MyContainerFuncApp' is starting...3/14/2018 5:42:04 PM [myteslaVM] Pull container image azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver3/14/2018 5:42:06 PM [myteslaVM] preview2-latest-nanoserver: Pulling from azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime3/14/2018 5:42:06 PM [myteslaVM] Digest: sha256:dfdb47a7638d0cdd1a42c603e3e59311ee0d229222f88329a7c561fc3d8b2ff3

    3/14/2018 5:42:06 PM [myteslaVM] Status: Image is up to date for azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver3/14/2018 5:42:06 PM [myteslaVM] The container image azfuncrun/azure-functions-runtime:preview2-latest-nanoserver has been pulled successfully!3/14/2018 5:42:06 PM [myteslaVM] Provisioning container MyContainerFuncApp_13/14/2018 5:42:07 PM [myteslaVM] 10dfbab15acef64780c34d5d01ded776a10d074500b33ba916b032920404d1d13/14/2018 5:42:07 PM [myteslaVM] C:\Program Files\Azure Functions Runtime\docker\docker.exe:
```

Comment: Is Hyper-V feature installed and running on your machine and is the docker service running? That error message "No hypervisor is present on this system." hints towards some problem with your virtualization infra.

Comment: I configured Hyper-V since Server Manager Tool. On Manage. Add Roles and Features Wizard.  It seems as running, however I dont know if there is some command to confirm is well configured.?

In fact, in services, there are some services for Hyper-V running.
-Data Exchange Service
-Guest Service Interface
-Guest Shutdown Service
-Heartbeat Service
-Host Compute Service
-PowerShell Direct Service
-Remote Desktop Virtualization
-Time Synch Service
-Virtual Machine Managment
-Volume Shadow Copy Req.

For Docker. 
I checked services and there is one service running.
-Docker Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Researching  more on the subject, I realized that it does not work for Basic Plan (SKU) for
virtual Machines.

Only works for SKU in Standard plan.

Applies for both  Windows Pro and Windows Server 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some research I did next steps in order to try to resolve this error.

1.Windows Server 2016 Configuration

https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=installing-windows-server-2016&author=greg-shields&name=installing-windows-server-2016-m2&clip=5&mode=live

```
--Install Features and Roles.
```

2.Install Hyper-V

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/install-the-hyper-v-role-on-windows-server

To check Hyper-V installed, run this cmd let in Power Shell.
Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName <computer_name>  

Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName MyteslaVM

To Install Hyper-V
Add-WindowsFeature –name RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools

    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f750d5e3-69f8-4cbd-a7aa-98e2fd41c618/need-to-install-hyperv-management-tools-on-server-2012-vm?forum=winserverhyperv
```

3.Execute Docker version.

4.Execute Dockerd "Daemon"  .

```
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40602674-can-t-start-docker-service-on-windows-server-vm
dockerd --debug

Stop-service docker
Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork -Force
Start-service docker
```

5.
    Get-VM | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

```
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/359
```

6.Install Docker

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -RequiredVersion 1.0.0.3
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

7.Install The latest azure-functions-core-tools:

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core

 Run npm i -g npm           **to update
```

8. Install .NET Core 2.0

   https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

9.To enable nested virtualization, you need to run the following cmdlet in the Hyper-V host:

```
Get-VM | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

10.Run Script

```
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19685
```

11.Download  azure-functions-runtime:2.0.0-nanoserver

```
docker pull microsoft/azure-functions-runtime:2.0.0-nanoserver-1709
```

12.One of the Hyper-V components is not running

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4d0761d-6048-4cb8-9a1f-1a2544b4ceb2/one-of-the-hyperv-components-is-not-running?forum=win10itprovirt

13.Disable Windows defender.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

It seems as Azuer Function runtime component is not working for Windows Server 2016,
because containers.

I tried it with a new Virtual Machine, with Windows 10 Pro. And it is now working.
Steps:

1. Create Virtual Machine, with Windows 10 Pro
2. Install/enable Hyper-V
3. Install and configure Component for Azure Functions.

[see image for Azure Function Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLEsG.png)